# How to remove possible "collisions" for the king in my chess program?

Tags: f#, chess

I have an assignment in which I am to make a simplified chess game with only rooks and kings. In this game I need to show the possible moves for the next turn for each piece. I have made is to that it lists every possible next turn based on it's abilities(the king can move 1 step all around it). However I haven't taken account for that I need to filter out moves which would potentially kill the king. The king cannot be moved to a square where the opponents rook is in the same horizontal or vertical line. 
The code basically runs on this method

```
let getVacantNOccupied (run : Position list) : (Position list * (chessPiece option)) =
    try
      // Find index of first non-vacant square of a run
      let idx = List.findIndex (fun (i, j) -> _board.[i,j].IsSome) run
      let (i,j) = run.[idx]
      let piece = _board.[i, j] // The first non-vacant neighbour
      if idx = 0
      then ([], piece)
      else (run.[..(idx-1)], piece)
    with
      _ -> (run, None) // outside the board
```

and

```
member this.availableMoves (piece : chessPiece) : (Position list * chessPiece list)  =
    match piece.position with
      None -> 
        ([],[])
      | Some p ->
        let convertNWrap = 
          (relativeToAbsolute p) >> getVacantNOccupied
        let vacantPieceLists = List.map convertNWrap piece.candiateRelativeMoves
        // Extract and merge lists of vacant squares
        let vacant = List.collect fst vacantPieceLists
        // Extract and merge lists of first obstruction pieces and filter out own pieces
        let opponent = List.choose snd vacantPieceLists
        (vacant, opponent)
```

How can I remove the squares where a rook could kill the king for possible squares?

Comment: This question needs more preparation to be answerable. Comments on the outer parts of your code: Good: You have type annotations for inputs and outputs. The names `Position` and `availableMoves` are good. Bad: 1. The names `getVacantNOccupied` and `run` are unclear. 2. It is unclear what the return types of your functions represent. In `getVacantNOccupied` it makes it impossible to comment on what this function does (without reading the internals) as the name also doesn't make it clear. In the case of `available moves`, why the output contains a `chessPiece list` is unclear.

Comment: 3. Throwing and catching exceptions in `getVacantNOccupied` is not a good method.

Comment: For my chess game I implemented a method that checks if any of the 8 squares is under attack by an enemy piece, and then that move is removed from the possible moves list (or add the ones that are not under attack). 

Maybe it is also possible to calculate possible moves at the end of opponents turn, and then use these squares as "forbidden" squares for the king? Might be a bit more expensive though.